# A set inequality problem

Tags: combinatorics

There is two different sets called set $a$ and $b$.Let $t$ be a positive integer,and put $t$ objects in another set called set $c$ ,and label the $t$ objects $c^1$,$c^2$...$c^t$.

Next,you put the objects form set $c$ to
either set $a$ or set $b$ one by one.(Order does not matter),such that **everytime a object was placed,the following statement must be true** :

*The set $b$ must have more objects than the set $a$(not same)*.

The question is, how many ways can we arrange the objects in the required way when $t$ changes? *Is there a formula for it?*

Thanks!

(I made the graph below when I was thinking of the question and found that when $t$ is odd,then it is just the number of $(t-1)$ objects $×2$ (*except 2*).When $k$ is even, then it is mutiplied by $3/2$,$5/3$,$7/4$. Does the formula have to be based on odd and even?)

($k$ value)

1. 1
2. 1
3. 2($×2$)
4. 3($×3/2$)
5. 6($×2$)
6. 10($×5/3$)
7. 20($×2$)
8. 35($×7/4$)
9. 70($×2$)

Comment: Look up the term 'Dyck paths' and apply the fact that the first element needs to go to set $b$.

Comment: @Woett Although it is very similar,but Dyck paths can end only in one point, and this can end in more than one result(like if t is 5 ,you can end in three ways (2,3),(1,4),(0,5).),so it is different from Dyck paths.

Comment: I apologize. The generalization is called Bertrands ballot theorem.

Comment: I think this is https://oeis.org/A001405 which is $n\choose{[n/2]}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know why that is true. When n is odd, n+1 will give the output of mutipliying by 2,which makes sense.But when n is even, it mutiplies by something instead of mutipliying by 2 and add the most left number.I don't know why that is exactly true.

Comment: You seem to be asking for the number of sequences of $A$s and $B$s of length $t$ such that every nonempty initial segment has more $B$s than $A$s. If the number of $A$s is $q\le t/2$ then by the [ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem) there are $\binom{t-1}q-\binom{t-1}{q-1}$ such sequences where $\binom n{-1}=0$. So your answer is $$\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac t2\right\rfloor}\left[\binom{t-1}q-\binom{t-1}{q-1}\right]=\binom{t-1}{\left\lfloor\frac t2\right\rfloor}=\binom{t-1}{\left\lceil\frac{t-1}2\right\rceil}$$ as noted out in @GerryMyerson's comment.

Comment: When $t$ is even, there must be at least two more in b than in a, so object $t+1$ can go to either a or b, so you multiply by two. When $t$ is odd, there might be just one more in b, in which case object $t+1$ must go in b, so there must be fewer than twice as many ways for $t+1$ as for $t$. I don't know why the formula works, either, but it certainly agrees with your numbers.